# How to get dataframe from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am doing a groupby practice. But it returning dict not dataframe. I fallowed some of the solutions from Stack Overflow even no luck.

My code:

```
result[comNewColName] = sourceDF.groupby(context, as_index=False)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation).reset_index()
```

and I tried:

```
result[comNewColName] = sourceDF.groupby(context)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation).reset_index()
```

and

```
result[comNewColName] = sourceDF.groupby(context, as_index=False)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation)
```

all three cases, I am getting dict only. But I should get dataframe

here:

```
comNewColName = "totalAmount"
context =['clientCode']
aggColumn = 'amount'
aggOperation = 'sum'
```

Comment: What is `result` ? It is DataFrame ? dictionary? Do you need create new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need new column created by aggregeted values use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), but assign to `sourceDF`:

```
sourceDF[comNewColName] = sourceDF.groupby(context)[aggColumn].transform(aggOperation)
```

Your solution return `DataFrame`:

```
df = sourceDF.groupby(context)[aggColumn].agg(aggOperation).reset_index()
print (type(df))
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, second solution working perfectly for me. thanks a lot.